# How to built C code with OpenCV and NDK for Android?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I'm creating an Android project on AndroidStudio 1.5.1 with OpenCV 3.1.0 and NDK_r10.

In my build.gradle I have:

```
// begin OpenCV
sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "D:\\Documents\\android-ndk\\ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
    //end OpenCV
```

I Have in my application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
```

And in my android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT:= D:\\Documents\\OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include D:\\Documents\\OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk\\OpenCV-android-sdk\\sdk\\native\\jni\\OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE     :=  MyLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  :=  opencv.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

My opencv.cpp

```
#include "opencv.h"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myapp_testCV(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrlabel)
{
    Mat& mGr  = *(Mat*)addrGray;
    Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrlabel;
    vector<KeyPoint> v;

    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FastFeatureDetector::create(50);
    detector->detect(mGr, v);
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        const KeyPoint& kp = v[i];
        circle(mRgb, Point(kp.pt.x, kp.pt.y), 10, Scalar(255,0,0,255));
    }
}
```

My opencv.h

```
#ifndef OPENCV_H
#define OPENCV_H

#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_myapp_testCV(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrlabel);

}
#endif //OPENCV_H
```

All builds steps are fine, but at running, I get excecptions:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.myapp.MainActivity.testCV:(JJ)V
at com.myapp.MainActivity.testCV(Native Method)

How can I solve this problem ?

I have try first with NDK example to compile successfully only C code without link to openCV.